# Reload an activity in Android without finish()

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

In iOS, there is a method to reload a `viewcontroller` without killing it, e.g.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

For example, when you change the button title, it will reload automatically.

Are there any similar method in Android?

I found some link such as [Reload activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android), but it need to `finish()` it

```
startActivity(getIntent()); finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `View` it's `invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()`. You don't need to redraw `Activity` manually and, in most cases, you don't need to redraw views too (all this stuff OS carrying for you).

If there is something in `onCreate` or `onStart` methods of your Activity, that you need to do  more than one time for single screen, it's better to rewise your code.