# NullPointer in everything I do in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I have to update an expandableList from server, I am using asyncTask to download and fill new values in local database, everything is done in doInBackground but after its done I tried to refresh my expandableList in onPostExecute but I am getting a nullPointer on the  very statement which runs fine before loading new data. All I am doing is calling the same method which instializes expandableList in the first place..

The method which intializes list for the first time:

```
public void initializeExpandableList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getValuesForList();
        setupList();
        setupClickListenersOnExpandList();

    }
```

And the code for `getValuesForList()` and `setUpList()` is:

```
public void getValuesForList() {

    // get which list_id are present in subtopic table

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    ArrayList<String> ids = myDbHelper.getListIdsFromSubTopic();

    ArrayList<String> typeList = myDbHelper.getTypeListFromDB(ids);
    // typeList = myDbHelper.getTypeListFromDB();
    Log.v("typelist", typeList + "");
    arrGroupelements = typeList.toArray(new String[typeList.size()]);

    Log.v("arrGrp", arrGroupelements.toString() + "");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> subtopics = myDbHelper.getChildForGroup();

    arrChildelements = new String[subtopics.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < subtopics.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> row = subtopics.get(i);
        arrChildelements[i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
    }
    Log.e("arrChildElements", arrChildelements.toString());

}
```

And for setUpList() method:

```
public void setupList() {
            expList.setAdapter(adap);
            // adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((BaseAdapter) expList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

After inserting data in doInBackground(), inside onPostExecute I am calling a method `refresh()` which again makes a call to initializeExpandableList() where I am getting null pointer.

```
private void refresh() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
initializeExpandableList();
    }
```

Instead of initializeExpandableLIst, also tried

```
((BaseAdapter) expList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and also tried restarting the activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent);
```

again getting null pointer in last line `startActivity(intent);`

What am I missing here??

Comment: I can suggest you to reload the activity on refresh click. That might solve your prob

Comment: how exactly do I  do that? I tried finishing and starting activity but that doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: finish();
startActivity(getIntent());

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android

Comment: already tried, NullPointer at startActivity(getIntent());

Comment: please finish the activity once.

Comment: Have you passed the context and the expandable list to the AsynTask ? in AsyncTask use Activity activity = (Activity) context; activity.startActivity();

Comment: passed "getApplicationContext()" in context and I'm calling refresh() method that exists in my activity and proceeding from there.

Comment: Merely posting code and saying there's a NPE somewhere won't help. You need to pinpoint where it occurs. Look for `caused by` in log cat, find the line number of the last executed method on stack trace, set up a break point there. Debug, and examine what variable in scope is null.

Comment: @Singularity its being caused by everything called in refresh(), be it notifydataSet, startActvity, initializeExpandableList()

Comment: What methods are you calling in `doInBackground()` ? Does any of these methods accesses ListView ?

Comment: not at all, just downloading json data and inserting in local database..

Comment: can you paste error log? it will be more clear then.

Comment: If refresh() and initializeExpandableList() are in the same scope (activity), then initializeExpandableList() itself can't throw a NPE. Post your whole (slimmed down to what matters) activity and ASyncTask.. + line where the NPE is thrown in THAT code

Comment: Also, you should not pass getApplicationContext() to the ASyncTask. This is the context for the entire application, not the activity. You should pass 'this', the activity, to the ASyncTask. So probably you are using Context as a parameter of the ASyncTask, cast it to the Activity type and call the refresh method. If it is not the right context, calling the refresh() method itself will cause a NPE. Posting the ASyncTask + NPE line location would make this clear.