# Android: Reload main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

**The up link is different to my problem**

i have this structure:
**Main -> MenuItem -> AlertDialog class -> Click Button -> (Reload) Main**

I want click button reload activity main. How i can make it?

Thanks

**CLASE MAIN **

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.MenuOpcColores);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.MenuOpcColores:
            CambiarColores colores = new CambiarColores(this, 
                    R.layout.cambiar_colores, 
                    R.string.cambiarColores, 
                    R.color.estandar, 
                    R.id.botonAplicarColor,
                    R.id.botonCancelarColor); 
            colores.show();  
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

**CLASE DIALOG**

```
public class CambiarColores extends Dialog implements          android.view.View.OnClickListener{  

Context context;


public CambiarColores(Context context, int vista, int titulo, int color, int id1, int id2) {  

    super(context);  
    this.context = context;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.vista = vista;
    this.color = color;
    this.id1 = id1;
    this.id2 = id2;
}  

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(vista);  
}  

@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  

    // REFRESH MAIN 

} 
}
```

Comment: finish the activity, start the activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restart an Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: this example is not equal

Comment: Where is the button in your `CambiarColores` class?

Answer (score 4):

to reload the activity, complete or finish the activity first and then call the intent.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

or follow this post,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283098/6780216

Answer (score 1):

On the `Button` click execute following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Maybe you can post some code. According to my current understanding I have edited the answer.

Comment: getAplicactionContext(), finish() and startActivity() are undefined... this is ok in main class but not in alert dialog class. **public class changeColors extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{**

Comment: getActivity() is undefined

Comment: Why don't you post your class in your question?? Instead of letting me guess what you have done.

Comment: @user3092292 Thanks for posting your code. On your button click execute the updated code. It should work now.