# How to refresh the activity which is not finished in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, counter, onresume

Is there any way to refresh or update the activity in android?
**for example:** I am having two activities **Counter1** and **Counter2** activity.Here in the two activities there is one text view(**tv_count**) and the two buttons(**bt_plus and bt_minus**), plus and minus button respectively.when the user clicks on the respective button **count(textview value)** will get increase & decrease, the **count** starts from zero now the **count=4**,where I am saving the count values in a model class, starting the second activity without finishing the first activity.

```
button_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Counter2.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Now I am navigating to the second activity where i can further increase the **count** value from 4,now **count=6.**

```
button_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();

        }
    });
```

when i click back the current activity will get finish.But the value of the **count** remains same **4** which should be updated to **6** in **Counter1** activity.

As per surfing, they are saying to finish the first activity before moving to second activity.***But i don't want to finish the first activity*** rather to do some operation **onResume() or onRestart() and onPause()**.

Solution need: To update the value of a count on the first activity without finishing and calling the activity explicitly.

Below are the referral links:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android)   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

This question might be asked already but I want some one to brief me clearly. 
It will be very helpful,Thanks in Advance..

**EDITED**:***Actually this is just about a single value and single textview actually my requirement is some thing else.. I am developing a restaurant app where there will be many products in list view and in expandable list view which is in a sliding tabs. when the user add pizza the count will get increase when the user search the same product in search view the count can be increased.. the increased count is updated in model class but in the list view of sliding tabs is not getting updated.***

Comment: i think the problem here can be that you are instantiating model class in both the activities if i am not wrong . Is that so ?

Comment: You said you are saving the value in model class?? how are you sending the values to Counter2 activity? generally you can send values to another activity through arguments.. but i cannot see that in your code.. so is your class static?

Comment: That is just an example.I have not posted my actual code which is too messy.where i have simplified it here with the counter,and no I am not instantiating on both.

Comment: @AsifSb have to tried to set value of your textview in onResume method?

Comment: whenever i am making changes in the count value ill do model.setCount(4);

Comment: calll model.setCount(4) will set the value of variable in your model class.. but you will need to update the textview... for this you can use onActivityResult method.. or create a interface with a method which is called whenever the values is changed.. implement that interface in your counter1 activity class and update the textiview in the interface method...

but as of your current requirement onActivityResult will work perfectly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91549/discussion-between-tarun-and-asif-sb).

Answer (score 1):

You can write `onActivityResult` method in **Counter2** `Activity` and pass the value  to **Counter1**.

In your **Counter1**:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(data.getExtras().containsKey("value")){
   txtview.setText(data.getStringExtra("value"));
  }
  }
```

In your **Counter2**:

```
 i.putExtra("value", value);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
```

Comment: You can pass your count to first activity and use however you want.Or else you can save the count in `SharedPreferences` and retrieve wherever required.This is the best solution since it can be accessed and edited anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data between activities, you should start a new Activity via `startActivityForResult()`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
```

If you want to send back data from the SecondActivity

```
button_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

And in your FirstActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            // Update your view and model with the returned value 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the **count** value from the **Counter1** activity to the **Counter2** activity. Increase it there and save it there. And while finishing the 2nd activity, send the the updated **counter** value back to the **Counter1** activity.

You can try something like this -

```
button_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Counter2.class);
            intent.putExtra("CURRENT_COUNTER_VALUE", counter);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
});
```

In the **Counter2** activity, you can retrieve the **counter** value like this -

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String counter = extras.getIntExtra("CURRENT_COUNTER_VALUE",0);

}
```

Then while finishing the **Counter2** activity -

```
button_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Counter1.class);
            intent.putExtra("CURRENT_COUNTER_VALUE", counter);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And retrieve the same way in **Counter1** activity's onResume() method.

Hope it helps.