# Android oncreateOption menu for reload a activity

Tags: android, onclick, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have Activity with Action Which have a **refresh icon in OnCreateOption Menu**.I want to **reload my current Activity On click this Icon** Click.But I don't know to use here click event.How to resolve this.

Comment: Look up `onOptionsItemClick()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload activity in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected` method like this way:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnuRefresh: // your menu item id
                reCreate();
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

There is a good example here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480103/2724418