# Refreshing Layout with EditText and Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made a form and connected it to a firebase database. It has an EditText in which you write something(e.x a suggestion) and then you press the button to submit it in the firebase database. But how can I refresh the whole xml file so I can write a new suggestion. I have tried this at first

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_suggestions);
```

But after that, the xml file was refreshed but I couldn't submit a new suggestion.
and then I tried this which works but its really annoying because if I press the back button it gets me back to the same page

```
Intent reportBugIntent = new Intent(ReportBug.this, ReportBug.class);
                startActivity(reportBugIntent);
```

Is the any other way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are! How about refreshing `Activity`: [Reload activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android)

The current code is useless because it will just return you to the current page, instead, you may wanna finish the current `Activity` by `finish()` method then doing such thing.

So:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Or:

```
// Refresh main activity upon close of dialog box
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, clsMainUIActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
this.finish(); //
```

As mentioned on the above link.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. Anyways, you could make the `EditText` text to zero -> "" like the other user mentioned but as you wish.

Comment: this is short and efficient: finish();
startActivity(getIntent());           By the way which one is the snappiest one?

Comment: The other answer by Krishna Sharma. `yourEditText.setText("");`. It also depends on what you are doing on the `Activity`. Just wanted you to take a look. Fair enough then.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to clear editText content on submit button click.

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            // Save content to firebase database
            // clear the editext
            editText.setText("");// where edit text is your suggestion edit text
       }
}
```